# Permanently set options such as metric units for W|A queries

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

Mathematica lets me be so lazy that I don't even have to switch to a browser to check the weather report:

[image]

The only problem is that it will automatically display the temperature and wind speed in Fahrenheit and miles per hour.  Unfortunately I don't speak Fahrenheit and I'd like to see it in Celsius.  When using W|A online, it is possible to create a user account and set W|A to metric permanently.

Is it possible to set preferences such as this one permanently (at least for the duration of a session) when using W|A from within Mathematica?

Comment: I know I can use `==` or click that little `+` and then use the Show Metric button.  The question is about setting the default though.  For example it is possible to log in to my W|A account from within Mathematica and let it use my personal preferences?

Comment: have you tried `SetOptions[WolframAlpha, PodStates -> {"Show metric"}]`. I can't really test as it shows stuff in metric units for me by default. Would be interesting to know what it is that determines the default...

Comment: @AlbertRetey This is the solution, can you post it as an answer?  AFAIK default is determined by location (IP address?)

Comment: just did that. As for the default: I was guessing that as well, but have you found any documentation on that? Probably that's too much to ask for as Wolfram|Alpha certainly makes such decisions based on its AI and noone knows where they come from :-).

Comment: @AlbertRetey I found some references in the W|A forums.  Some people were complaining about getting non-metric in Europe.  I guess that if the browser-based W|A determines location based on IP, then so does Mathematica.  But maybe it's based on `$GeoLocation` and I could have tried setting that (which would also change which city the weather is reported for).

Comment: "weather in celcius" ==> "Latest recorded weather for Cuciu, Romania"... Sigh. Although, I suppose "weather" in "Celcius", a unit of temperature, is a ridiculous question :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the options for `WolframAlpha` in the usual way. The option to change is:

```
SetOptions[WolframAlpha, PodStates -> {"Show metric"}]
```

as for me (for whatever reason) it was the default to show metric units, I could verify with:

```
SetOptions[WolframAlpha, PodStates -> {"Show non-metric"}]
```

that this seems indeed to affect also the answers to the free form input-cells.