# Setting default units for output

Tags: units

Is it possible to set a default set of units for output?

I've just discovered the joys of units and `Quantity`. Ideally, I'd like to be able to tell Mathematica to always convert to SI units. I'm aware I could `UnitConvert` every entry, but that's not what I'm after: I want to set and forget. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Digging around the docs is making me think the answer is "No, it isn't", which is disappointing.

Edit:

This is not the same as setting the units to default in metric. My default is metric. However, Mathematica will keep things in pre-defined quantities if I use them. As an arbitrary example, consider below:

```
$Unitsystem
mass = 10 Quantity["SolarMass"]
inertia = 2/5 mass
```

The output of this is

```
Metric
Quantity[10, "SolarMass"]
Quantity[400, ("Meters")^2 "SolarMass"]
```

i.e. it does not convert from solar mass units, even though my unit system is metric. I could explicitly tell it to convert every line, but that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: You can always use `$Post = Replace[q_Quantity:>UnitConvert[q]]`

Comment: .. or `$Post =If[Head[#] === Quantity, UnitConvert[#], #]&` or `$PrePrint = If[Head[#] === Quantity,  UnitConvert[#],  #]&`.

Comment: Also possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44639/12

Comment: You could add the line `$UnitSystem = "Metric"` to your init.m file.

Comment: I'll try the first two and see if it works. Thanks!

Comment: I am voting to reopen this post so that @b3m2a1 can convert his/her comment into an answer. Moreover, OP made clear that this is not a precise duplicate.

Comment: Question is open now and still no answer.